# Compiling SCIP: 'spxsolver.h' file not found

Tags: optimization, scip

I am trying to compile SCIP using the following command:

```
make ZLIB=false READLINE=false GMP=false
```

Anyone has idea how to handle this issue?

```
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/objscip/objsepa.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/objscip/objvardata.o
-> generating library lib/libobjscip-3.1.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/lpi/lpi_spx.o
src/lpi/lpi_spx.cpp:76:10: fatal error: 'spxsolver.h' file not found
#include "spxsolver.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/lpi/lpi_spx.o] Error 1
make: *** [libs] Error 2
```

Note: I am using Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was installing the `scip-3.1.1.tgz` rather than 
`scipoptsuite-3.1.1.tgz`. Running `make` on `scipoptsuite-3.1.1.tgz` runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

SCIP uses external LP-solvers such as [SoPlex](http://soplex.zib.de) (by default) as underlying LP-solver. The LP-solver needs to be linked in at compilation time. Here is how you do that:

1. Download and unpack SoPlex and compile it in a separate directory, e.g., `~/soplex`
2. Link SoPlex into SCIP. The easiest way is to call `make links` from your SCIP directory

Please refer to the [Installation guide of SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/MAKE.php) for more details, especially the step-by-step example No. 1.